# Does MongoCR authentication work with Compose.io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, compose-db

I'm trying to use [promised-mongo](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo) to access a MongoDB database hosted on Compose.io. I am using the same connection string I use to accept the DB using the `mongo` CLI tool, but when I try to connect I get:

`err { [MongoError: auth failed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'auth failed',
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'auth failed',
  code: 18 }`

I nosed around in the `promised-mongo` code a bit and it appears to be using a standard MongoDB library called [MongoCR](https://docs.omniref.com/js/npm/mongodb-core/1.0.2/symbols/MongoCR) for the authentication. Is this authentication approach simply incompatible with Compose.io, or do I have to change the config of our database somehow or adapt the connection string?

Comment: Actually this appears to be built on [mongodb-core](https://github.com/christkv/mongodb-core) ( as it is generally advised for any higher level adaptations in nodejs to do ). You might be getting confused by the difference between [MONGODB-CR and SCRAM-SHA1](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/security-scram-sha-1/) authentication in MongoDB releases. But this is entirely dependant which version is being offered ( and/or chosen by you ) with your provider. The mongodb-core that should be installed supports both. That's what's in the dependencies list anyway.

Comment: I've haven't delved too deeply into the code, but have a look at https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo/blob/master/lib/Database.js#L115. It seems to me like the `mongocr` auth provider is hardcoded. I'm assuming that Compose.io doesn't support this, but I don't see an obvious way to change this to use a different auth provider.

Comment: FWIW the error seems to go away if I set `ssl: true` in the options. I'm not sure whether this is really the root cause of the issue or not. It probably isn't due to the auth mechanism since I looked more closely and a whole range of auth providers are set in the `Server` constructor of `mongodb-core` by default.

In any case I still can't get `promised-mongo` to return any results from the database. I've given up and switched to `mongojs`, which seems to work fine. Pity about the promises though.

Comment: Worth taking a look at the standard nativemongodb driver too https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo/issues/35 that should return promises if you don't provide a callback.